# How can I use pyperclip on EC2?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, pyperclip

When I try to run my program on EC2, I cannot use the pyperclip library

This is my code

```
import pyperclip

pyperclip.copy('Hello, World!')
text_copied = pyperclip.paste()

print(text_copied)
```

And Error

```
pyperclip.PyperclipException: 
    Pyperclip could not find a copy/paste mechanism for your system.
    For more information, please visit https://pyperclip.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#not-implemented-error
```

How can I use pyperclip on EC2?

I have no idea.
Nobody help me?

I did [sudo yum install xclip] already.

I expect the reason of Linux Environment but I have no idea about details.

Comment: *Why* are you trying to use pyperclip on EC2?

Comment: sudo apt-get install xclip

Comment: Because I want to use my python code on the AWS. If I can change another library or method, I should want to do.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.